# How to update a column base on another column's value from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a `table A`, with 2 main columns: `Name` and `Settings`.
The `Settings` column will have 3 values: 1, 2 or 3.

For ex:

```
Name     Settings
Andre        1
Andre        1
Betty        3
Charles      1
Charles      1
```

Note that 1 `Name` can only have 1 `Settings`: 1, 2 or 3

I have another `table B`, with 2 main columns: `Name` and `Type`.
The `Type` column consists of 3 values: `'TypeA'`, `'TypeB'` and `'TypeC'`.

For ex:

```
Name       Type
Andre      TypeA
Andre      TypeA
Andre      TypeC
Betty      TypeB
Betty      TypeB
Charles    TypeB
Charles    TypeA
Charles    TypeA
```

Note that 1 `Name` can have multiple same or not same `Type`. And we are not consider about `TypeC`, just `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

Now I want to update the `Settings` column from `table A` using the `'Type'` column from `table B`, if:

- The `Type` column from `table B` is having the value of `'TypeA'`, then set all the records, which is having the same `Name` of both table, to 1 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.
- The `Type` column from `table B` is having the value of `'TypeB'`, then set all the records, which is having the same `Name` of both table, to 2 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.
- The `Type` column from `table B` is having both of the value of `'TypeA'` and `'TypeB'`, then set all the records, which is having the same `Name` of both table, to 3 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.

The result from `table A` will become like this:

```
Name     Settings
Andre        1
Andre        1
Andre        1
Betty        2
Charles      3
Charles      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need an update join statement:

```
UPDATE a
SET    settings = CASE type WHEN 'TypeA' THEN 1
                            WHEN 'TypeB' THEN 2
                  END
FROM   tablsA a
JOIN   tableB b ON a.name = b.name
WHERE  type IN ('TypeA', 'TypeB') -- just a precaution
```

Comment: A much needed precaution otherwise the others (non matching) types will be updated to NULL when you didnt add the where clause..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yup, that's why it's there. From the OP's description, it's unclear if there are indeed other types in the table or not. though.

Comment: Indeed still i would add in ELSE type  = type in the case clause as extra safety net for cases where the WHERE clause and CASE statement does not match up it can happen when writting large queries.. But still who would execute these kind off queries on a production database without testing it on a small copy of the production database as test

Comment: @Mureinik you are right there are more values in the "Type" column, but I just consider "TypeA" and "TypeB" for my query. Also there is another condition I forgot to add in, just edited the question. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I see more than one option.

You could consider normalize those tables and add foreign key with cascading the updates.

You could replace one of those tables just a view and map the values; it depends which table can be updated. If both receiving updates this solution may only work if you use indexed views.

If you have different or overlapping settings on different types , also maybe with dependency's from users, you might need an mapping table where you map Type to Settings.

Also it’s possible, to use triggers for those things to ensure consistency, but you should prefer a proper table layout with correct foreign keys.

It may also help to give more details about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to aggregate the second table before `JOIN`ing:

```
UPDATE a
    SET settings = (CASE WHEN num_a > 0 AND num_b = 0 THEN 1
                         WHEN num_b > 0 THEN 2
                         ELSE 3
                    END)
FROM tablsA a JOIN
     (SELECT b.name,
             SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'TypeA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_a,
             SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'TypeB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_B
      FROM tableB b
      GROUP BY b.name
     ) b
     ON a.name = b.name
```